# Point root domain to a subdomain of another site

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain

How can I point my root domain `example.com` to a subdomain of another site `subdomain.example2.com`?

he subdomain is wildcard subdomain. I have cPanel root server access.

I just want to make it looks like Shopify. A Shopify store example.shopify.com can be accessible from store owners custom domain. Do we need to edit virtual host file or anything? We are using cpanel, Apache server.

Comment: I edited your comment into your post.  If you have further updates, please use the "edit" feature yourself rather than commenting with additional info.

Answer (score -2):

You would use the cname DNS record for that

Comment: One sentence answers tend not to be very helpful. You should expand your answer to include more detail.

Comment: Any example please?

Comment: In addition to being a short answer, just creating a DNS record is not sufficient to solve the problem.